# Network Manager script when interface up?

Tags: network-manager

Because I am using *Bionic Beaver/Ubuntu 18.04*, the network settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` are being ignored and the settings in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/'eth0'` are being used for i) static ip ii) gateway etc.

I wish to restart the sshd service every time the interface comes up. It doesn't work in the normal place `/etc/network/interfaces` since I'm using Gnome. Where can I place a NetworkManager script to be run every time a specific interface comes up?

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` no longer controls networking in 18.04. It is managed by *netplan*. I suggest that you transfer your settings there. https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: @chili555 not 100% accurate. The /etc/netplan/*.yaml file can be set to use NetworkManager, just like the good old days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to create *dispatchers scripts* in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`. For example, you could log events in `journald` by placing the following script at `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/log-iface-events.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

interface=$1
event=$2

echo "$interface received $event" | systemd-cat -p info -t dispatch_script
```

Remember to give it execution permissions:

```
chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/log-iface-events.sh
```

The bad news is that scripts are no longer tied to a given interface or events such as *up* or *down*. Hence, you must check all of that in your script. If you want this script to run only for `eth0`, you must filter that by hand putting something like the following in your script:

```
[[ $interface == "eth0" ]] || return 0
```

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

interface=$1
event=$2

if [[ $interface != "eth0" ]] || [[ $event != "up" ]]
then
  return 0
fi

# place your commands bellow this line
```

Will run only if it is dealing with `up` events for `eth0` interface.

You can have many scripts. According to `man 8 networkmanager`, scripts will run in alphabetical order. This seems to include the scripts in subdirectories. You MUST read this manpage.

Comment: Inside my `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` I have 3 sub-directories and one executable named `01-ifupdown`. Exactly where should I put my commands? :/

Comment: @JSStuball I made changes to address your question.

Comment: Please could you(/someone) address 1) how the choice of script filename affects behaviour, and 2) why the `01-ifupdown` is the sole executable file in the `dispatcher.d` directory after installation?

Comment: @JSStuball I addressed the first point. About the second, it seems to bridge the functionalities of the old `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-up.d` with network-manager, but I suspect it will be deprecated soon.

Comment: I am trying to write a script using this, but my NetworkManager only reacts to `event := down` when `nmcli` detects the connection loss, and `event := up` when `nmcli` confirms a DHCP configuration has been accepted. How can I make the dispatcher react at the moment where `nmcli` switches from `state := unavailable` to `state := connecting` ?

Comment: this is perfect.  The only thing I would add is that this event appears to fire multiple times on boot.  for me appeared to fire 5 times on boot.

Comment: this is perfect.  The only thing I would add is that this event appears to fire multiple times on boot.  for me appeared to fire 5 times on boot.

Comment: May I recommend reading this man page too:

    man 8 NetworkManager-dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

[network-manager-connection-action](https://blog.izissise.net/posts/network-manager-connection-action/) connects to dbus and listen for connections state changes. Running using user's privileges.

Shameless plug, I'm the author